# excluding certain files based on filename

Tags: php, file, directory

So I have a code snippet that reads a directory and performs certain actions on the files inside. I have an array of filenames to exclude. My code looks like this:

```
$excluded = array(".","..","thumbs.db");

if($fh = @opendir($dir)) 
{
    while(false !== ($file = @readdir($fh))) 
    {
       if(in_array(strtolower($file),$excluded))
       {
          continue;
       }
       //do processing here...
```

Now, I want it that zip files also should be excluded. Since I do not know what name they might exist in, I will need to skip them based on extension.

Now I know I can split the filename and look at the last element to see if it zip etc, but what I wanted to ask is, is there a way to achieve it within the constraints of what is coded already - like adding it like this, and then tweaking the loop to handle it...

```
 $excluded = array(".","..","thumbs.db","*.zip");
```

Comment: [`fnmatch`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$excluded = array(".","..","thumbs.db");
$excludedExtensions = array(".zip",".rar");

if($fh = @opendir($dir)) 
{
    while(false !== ($file = @readdir($fh))) 
    {
       if(in_array(strtolower($file),$excluded) || 
          in_array(strtolower(substr($file, -4)), $excludedExtensions) )
       {
          continue;
       }
       //do processing here...
```

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but i don't think it's possible to do the way you wanted it to :(

*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

*EDIT*

I wanted to make a more reliable way to do this, since there is some files which have 4 or even 5 letters in their extension. After looking though the PHP manual, i found this:

```
$excluded = array(".","..","thumbs.db");
$excludedExtensions = array(".zip",".rar", ".7z", ".jpeg", ".phtml");

if($fh = @opendir($dir)) 
{
    while(false !== ($file = @readdir($fh))) 
    {
       $path_parts = pathinfo($file);

       if(in_array(strtolower($file),$excluded) ||
          in_array(strtolower($path_parts['extension'])) )
       {
          continue;
       }
       //do processing here...
```

See more here: [PHP manual: pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)